# How to customize Powerbuilder Specify Version Information

Tags: deployment, version, powerbuilder

I usually make a lot of application deployment and it is very timeconsuming and uncomfortable every time to overwrite the default Powerbuilder Version information. So usually I do not bother with this. But I thought there could be a solution to give this "default" information somehow to the PowerBuilder, so after the default values were filled I would only need to overwrite the exact version number. Do anybody have an idea? Thanx in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at VersionEdit from ECrane?

We actually use PowerGen from them as well for production PowerBuilder compiles and the same capability is in there.

http://ecrane.com/

Comment: Thx Bruce. I didn't know this tools, but I think these tools are pretty expensive for our project. I thought there is an INI file, or registry settings where I could change these information. Do you know any other possibilities?

Comment: You may be looking at PowerGen.  It looks like they sell VersionEdit seperately still.  It's only $75.

http://ecrane.com/store/

As I mentioned in response to Real's post, the PowerBuilder generated EXE is a custom EXE, and most utilies that try to set this information will actually corrupt the EXE.  VersionEdit is the only utility I know of that handles is correctly on the generated executable.

Hugh's suggestion is about the only other option.  Create the executable with the version, company, copyright information to begin with.  PowerGen is one way to do that, OracScript is another.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you build your application with PBORCA (my preference) or OrcaScript. Both support setting the executable properties. PBORCA can read the properties from an INI file.
We use a small Java program to get the next version number from a database and update the INI file. If you're doing any more than clicking a button to build and deploy your app, you're working too hard. We have Jenkins jobs that watch the SVN repository and build our projects automatically.

This is what one of the INI files for PBORCA looks like before the version is set

```
[exeproperties]
companyname=BogoSoft
productname=BogoMojo
description=BogoMojo is BogoMojo
copyright=Reserved Rights
fileversion=5.01
fileversionnum=2
;productversion=
productversionnum=0002
;manifestinfo=

[config]
targetname=bogo.pbt
exename=bogomojo.exe
iconname=images\\bogo1.ico
pbrname=bogo.pbr
```

The Script for PBORCA has

```
profile string %%WORKSPACE%%\build.ini, config, targetname
profile string %%WORKSPACE%%\build.ini, config, exename
profile string %%WORKSPACE%%\build.ini, config, iconname
profile string %%WORKSPACE%%\build.ini, config, pbrname
profile exeinfo %%WORKSPACE%%\build.ini, exeproperties
```